# Printing, separating content into pages and bootstrap

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to divide content into proper pages during a print process. I also have bootstrap (4.3.1) included, which causes the page to appear larger than A4 for some reason

I have a few div's each of size 29.7cm X 21cm (A4). If I do not include bootstrap, they are exactly the size of a page, but If I add bootstrap css, they become smaller. (or the page becomes larger???)

What CSS do I have to rewrite to have them properly scaled?

https://jsfiddle.net/8q5tbcdk/

(the fiddle calls `window.print()` to reproduce the problem)

```
<div>
    <div class="page red"></div>
    <div class="page blue"></div>
    <div class="page green"></div>
</div>
```

---

```
.page {
    height: 297mm;
    width: 210mm;
    size: A4;
    margin: 0;
}

.red {
    background: red;
}

.blue {
    background: blue;
}

.green {
    background: green;
}
```

Comment: FYI, that’s not what the term “pagination” means. Which version of bootstrap? Please include it in your fiddle, otherwise that has very little purpose to begin with.

Comment: Please remove that `window.print()` from your fiddle. It causes the print dialog to appear on page load. Also, have you tried using `@media print`?

Comment: @disinfor I guess they added it, because the problem probably only shows when print styles get applied. Such situations can be a pain to debug, browser dev tools don’t work well in print preview mode. Perhaps wrapping the CSS that was shown into a print media query as you suggested, and then slapping `!important` on everything might help already, if BS is overwriting styles for these specific elements. If it results from something else, margins/paddings on outer elements, it might need some more debugging …

Comment: @misorude yeah, I get why the OP did it...I just found it annoying :). Print styles are a total PITA to diagnose - but without knowing more about what was actually tried, it's hard for us to know where to start.

Comment: @misorude The bootstrap is already added in fiddle. 4.3.1

Comment: @disinfor Because the issue is reproduced only when window.print() is called. I'll add a warning to the question

Comment: @disinfor And I also tried this with `@media`, didn't help

Answer (score 0):

After disecting bootstrap code by parts, I found the part that was responsible for the problem:

```
@media print {
 body {
    min-width: 992px !important;
  }
  .container {
    min-width: 992px !important;
  }
  @page {
    size: a3;
  }
}
```

No idea why `Bootstrap` has decided it is a good idea to do that - I'd love to hear an explanation/reasoning.
So the solution is to:

```
@media print {
   body {
    min-width: inherit !important;
  }
  .container {
    min-width: inherit !important;
  }
  @page {
    size: a4;
  }
}
```